# Can JRXML extend data source before using it?

Tags: jasper-reports

I use the same data source for generating several reports. One of the reports needs to be printed with a few empty lines ("reserve") at the bottom, so that users can manually write missing data by hand if needed.

E.g.:

```
+---------+-------------+
| item 1  | bla bla     |
+---------+-------------+
| item 2  | foo         |
+---------+-------------+
|         |             |   <--- here user can just add forgotten
+---------+-------------+        items with a pen
|         |             |
+---------+-------------+
```

The easiest for the JRXML would be if there were several records of `null`s at the end of the data source. Then it would just print its "details" band a few times with no text, just as required. However, the data source is reused for other reports which certainly don't want this.

Can I somehow inject such empty lines into the data source in JRXML itself, just before report filling?

Comment: What datasource are you using?

Comment: Custom implementation of `JRRewindableDataSource`, provided by the application to JR library.

Comment: I have posted an answer, the "normal way" would be to use a group footer when you need extra records (do something after detail band), but you could wrap the datasource or implement a special function in your custom datasource (that you could activate by calling it from jrxml or scriptlet) returning empty records (with null or whatever you prefer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your CustomDataSource and set it from jrxml to generate extra records when needed:

**Example**

```java
public class JRExtraEmptyRecordsDataSource extends JRBeanCollectionDataSource {

    private int nrOfEmptyRecords=0;
    private int currentExtraRecord = 0;

    public JRExtraEmptyRecordsDataSource(Collection<?> beanCollection) {
        super(beanCollection);
    }       

    @Override
    public Object getFieldValue(JRField field) throws JRException {
        if (currentExtraRecord==0){
            return super.getFieldValue(field);
        }
        Class<?> theCorrectClass = field.getValueClass();
        //Implement your logic to return correct class (reflection or switch) if you need speciall values
        //or just return null
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next() {
        boolean next = super.next();
        if (next){
            return true;
        }
        currentExtraRecord++;
        return currentExtraRecord<=nrOfEmptyRecords;
    }

    @Override
    public void moveFirst() {
        super.moveFirst();
        currentExtraRecord=0;
    }


    public int getNrOfEmptyRecords() {
        return nrOfEmptyRecords;
    }

    public int setNrOfEmptyRecords(int nrOfEmptyRecords) {
        this.nrOfEmptyRecords = nrOfEmptyRecords;
        return this.nrOfEmptyRecords;//Lets return something for variable
    }

}
```

When you need **extra empty records** add this variable definition in your jrxml

```xml
<variable name="extraRecords" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[((my.package.JRExtraEmptyRecordsDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).setNrOfEmptyRecords(2)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

## I do not have custom datasource what can I do?

Normally **without** custom datasource, you can use the `columnFooter` with the attribute `isFloatColumnFooter="true"` (or a dummy group footer band) to display extra info at the end of your detail band. Probably I would choose this method anyway since it helps to customize the extra rows and avoid checking for `null` in the normal `detail` band

If you need dynamically to indicate the number of empty records, include a subreport with an empty record and pass as datasource [JREmptyDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JREmptyDataSource.html)

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(P{nrOfEmptyRecords})
```

Comment: I cannot modify the data source in the application, because it is used in other reports, as I mentioned in the question. I can only "extend" it afterwards, and this must be initiated by JRXML, so some do that, some not. Group footer *could* in principle be used, but it is kinda ugly. What if that my details band is complicated and I'd rather not duplicate it all in the footer?

Comment: @doublep Wrapping the datasource, you are not modifying it, you are deciding when you call the fillManager if you like empty records or not. Are we allowed to change the your custom datasource in some way?, can we add implementation that is called (from jrxml) when we need it?

Comment: Yes, internally it's an `ArrayList`. It can be modified by reports after application creates it.

Comment: About wrapping: I don't want the application to bother with what report is going to do. I.e. application shouldn't have to think "I need to wrap it for report X because it needs empty rows, but not for report Y". Reports are created at runtime, while application is a web server, which might be running without changes for several months. I.e. I just cannot change it every time I change a report.

Comment: @doublep, ok no wrapping I have edit the answer on how you can implement extra records in your current custom datasource, when you need you set the number of records from the jrxml by defining a dummy variable with defaultExpression.

Comment: Aha, so, basically, variable initialization modifies data source by side-effect? I.e. the variable is only needed for its initialization code here?

Comment: I have left the standard method using group bands, since I would probably choose this instead of checking for null ecc, and you can design as you like the fields for manual input, more space or other special customization

Comment: @doublep, its need to send the number of extra records (default 0), since its initialValueExpression it will be called once in the beginning.

Comment: Feels a bit ugly, but I suppose that's the way it usually is with JR. But now it conforms to my requirements that it's the report that initiates the changes. Thank you.

Comment: @doublep If you wanted it more beautiful, you can let it be set from a scriptlet, but I do not really see any sense in this. (just some extra classes). Design it in groupFooter ; )

Comment: Scriptlet goes back into the application again. Or at least we don't have a way to add scriptlets at runtime, just JRXML files.

Comment: @doublep Scriplet is a class of yours  (added on deploy)  you add it to the jrxml by setting the scriptletClass attribute on the jasperReport tag (then on begin, you could read a parameter and then enable your datasource for empty records), maybe more beautiful, but seems like overkill.